# @AutoConfigureAfter not working as desired

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have 3 spring-boot-starter projects

One of the autoconfiguration class has the following code:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(value = Config.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {FileGeneratorConfig.class, FileUploaderConfig.class})
public class JobConfig
```

FileGeneratorConfig and FileUploaderConfig are also autoconfiguration classes.

I was expecting that beans created in FileUploaderConfig will be created first. So test this I had put a break point in the method that creates bean in JobConfig and FileUploaderConfig. But the break point hits JobConfig first which makes me believe that my @AutoConfigureAfter is not working. Is that the right assumption.

Also in FileUploaderConfig i have this:

```
@Bean
    FileUtilContainer fileUtilContainer(FileUtilContainerProperties fileUtilContainerProperties){
        return new FileUtilContainer(FileUtil.createDirectory(fileUtilContainerProperties.getArchive()),
                                     FileUtil.createDirectory(fileUtilContainerProperties.getWorking()),
                                     FileUtil.createDirectory(fileUtilContainerProperties.getConfirmation()), 
                                     FileUtil.createDirectory(fileUtilContainerProperties.getConfirmationProcessed()),
                                     FileUtil.createDirectory(fileUtilContainerProperties.getError()), 
                                     FileUtil.createDirectory(fileUtilContainerProperties.getErrorProcessed()));
    }
```

and FileUtilContainerProperties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "batch.letter.directory", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class FileUtilContainerProperties
```

but it is not creating FileUtilContainerProperties bean. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoConfigureAfter controls the order in which the configuration files are processed and their bean definitions are created. The order in which beans are created from those definitions is a separate concern and depends on, among other things, the dependencies that exist between your beans.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. What about the second part where @Component is not working. FileUtilContainerProperties was not added to the context?

Comment: I'd guess it's in a package that isn't being component scanned. It's best to avoid relying on component scanning in your auto-configuration. I'd use `@EnableConfigurationProperties(FileUtilContainerProperties.class)` on`FileUploaderConfig` instead.

Comment: Thanks Andy I used that and it works fine. So I guess as a rule of thumb when using AutoConfiguration we should avoid component scanning and use @EnableConfigurationProperties right?